# Finding unique combinations based only on one of the columns using Alteryx

Tags: r, alteryx

I have the follow sample of a large dataset:

[image]

I am trying to establish which of the colours are exclusive to the packs, as it should show on the exclusive colour column. 
I am using Alteryx, but can also be R.

I wonder how can I assess if the colour on the second column is exclusive to the pack on the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Alteryx solution: Summarize counting distinct pack per color; a distinct pack count greater than 1 for any colour basically means FALSE for your desired column. Therefore: Summary Tool, Formula Tool, and Join back to your original data. (see screenshot).
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` you can `group_by` `colour` and check to see if there is only one `unique` `Pack`:

```
library(dplyr)

res <- df %>% group_by(colour) %>% mutate(exclusive.colour=(length(unique(Pack))==1))
```

With your data, noting that the expected result for `PURPLE` should be `FALSE` because it is in `Pack`s `C` and `D`:

```
print(res)
##Source: local data frame [19 x 3]
##Groups: colour [11]
##
##     Pack colour exclusive.colour
##   <fctr> <fctr>            <lgl>
##1       A  WHITE            FALSE
##2       A  BLACK            FALSE
##3       B  WHITE            FALSE
##4       B  GREEN             TRUE
##5       C  WHITE            FALSE
##6       C YELLOW             TRUE
##7       C  BLACK            FALSE
##8       C PURPLE            FALSE
##9       C    RED             TRUE
##10      C  BLACK            FALSE
##11      D PURPLE            FALSE
##12      D   BLUE             TRUE
##13      D  WHITE            FALSE
##14      D  BROWN             TRUE
##15      D ORANGE             TRUE
##16      D  BLACK            FALSE
##17      D  WHITE            FALSE
##18      D   LIME             TRUE
##19      D   PINK             TRUE
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(Pack = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), colour = structure(c(10L, 
1L, 10L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
10L, 5L, 7L), .Label = c("BLACK", "BLUE", "BROWN", "GREEN", "LIME", 
"ORANGE", "PINK", "PURPLE", "RED", "WHITE", "YELLOW"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Pack", 
"colour"), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
##   Pack colour
##1     A  WHITE
##2     A  BLACK
##3     B  WHITE
##4     B  GREEN
##5     C  WHITE
##6     C YELLOW
##7     C  BLACK
##8     C PURPLE
##9     C    RED
##10    C  BLACK
##11    D PURPLE
##12    D   BLUE
##13    D  WHITE
##14    D  BROWN
##15    D ORANGE
##16    D  BLACK
##17    D  WHITE
##18    D   LIME
##19    D   PINK
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
set.seed(12)

#generate data. Instead of colours I have upper case letters
d <-  data.frame(pack = rep(letters[1:6], each = 5), 
                 colour = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 30, replace = TRUE), 
                 exclusivecolour = NA)

# For each item in column 'colour', get all items in column 'pack' with that colour. 
#   If there is 1 unique value, it is exclusive.
d$exclusivecolour <- sapply(d$colour, function(x) length(unique(d$pack[d$colour == x])) == 1)
```